# Fortran + OpenMP code with a subroutine stops abruptly

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a piece of experimental code that works perfectly with serial compilation and execution. When I compile it with openmp option on ifort (on ubuntu), the compilation goes on fine but the execution stops abruptly. The code is as follows:

```
!!!!!!!! module
module array
implicit none
  real(kind=8),allocatable :: y(:)
end module array

module nonarray
implicit none
 real(kind=8):: aa
end module nonarray

use nonarray; use array
implicit none
integer(kind=8):: iter,i
integer(kind=8),parameter:: id=1
real(kind=8),allocatable:: yt(:)

allocate(y(id)); allocate(yt(id)); y=0.d0; yt=0.d0

aa=4.d0 !!A SYSTEM PARAMETER

 !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(y,yt,iter,i)
 !$OMP DO

   loop1: do iter=1,20 !! THE INITIAL CONDITION LOOP
    call random_number(y)!! RANDOM INITIALIZATION OF THE VARIABLE

      loop2: do i=1,10000  !! ITERATION OF THE SYSTEM
       call evolve(yt)
       y=yt
      enddo loop2     !! END OF SYSTEM ITERATION

     write(1,*)aa,yt

   enddo loop1 !!INITIAL CONDITION ITERATION DONE

 !$OMP ENDDO
 !$OMP END PARALLEL
stop
end

recursive subroutine evolve(yevl)
use nonarray; use array
implicit none
integer(kind=8),parameter:: id=1
real(kind=8):: xf
real(kind=8),intent(out):: yevl(id)

  xf=aa*y(1)*(1.d0-y(1))
  yevl(1)=xf

end subroutine evolve
```

For compilation I use the following command:
    *ifort -openmp -fpp test.f90*.

test.f90 being the name of the program. 
Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an OMP expert, but I think if the subroutine `evolve` should see a different (private) `y` in each thread, you should pass it directly from within the parallelized code block to the subroutine instead of importing it from an external module:

```
module common
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = real64
  real(dp) :: aa

contains

  subroutine evolve(y, yevl)
    implicit none
    real(dp), intent(in) :: y(:)
    real(dp), intent(out):: yevl(:)

    yevl(1) = aa * y(1) * (1.0_dp - y(1))

  end subroutine evolve

end module common


program test
  use common
  implicit none

  integer :: iter, i
  real(dp), allocatable :: yt(:), y(:)

  allocate(yt(1), y(1))
  y(:) = 0.0_dp
  yt(:) = 0.0_dp
  aa = 4.0_dp

  !$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(y,yt,iter,i)
  loop1: do iter = 1, 20
    call random_number(y)
    loop2: do i = 1, 10000
      call evolve(y, yt)
      y = yt
    end do loop2
    write(*,*) aa, yt
  end do loop1
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

end program test
```

Just an additional warning: the code above worked with various compilers (nagfor 5.3.1, gfortran 4.6.3, ifort 13.0.1), but not with ifort 12.1.6. So, although I can't see any obvious problems with it, I may have messed up something.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. The problem seems exactly as you suggested. The code is working good. I will see what other problems show up (if at all they show up) and keep this discussion thread updated. Further, maybe I have an idea regarding the problem with ifort12.1.6. The Older version was missing some features with allocatable arrays I think (as much as I could understand by reading on different forums) and the problem stems from that. I just updated my version to ifort 13.1.0 and it seems to be working good. Thank you so much for your answer yet again. It's been a big help.

Comment: According to the customs on Stackoverflow, you should not discuss further (different) problems in this thread. Every thread usually contains one question only. If you think, the question is fully answered by any of the answers, you should consider to accept it as the final answer at some point. If you experience other problems, you should ask it as a separate question. See the [Stackoverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for details.